# hide images on form using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have images to pick the date.  and I want to hide them on form load.

```
<div id="readOnly">
<table>
<td>
<input id="date" class="date hasDatepicker" type="text" name="date" maxlength="10"      size="10" readonly="">
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="...">
</td>
</table>
</div>
```

My javascript works in firebug "Console" for testing sake; but on form load it is not hiding the img (date picker).

```
$('div[id^="readOnly"]').find("img").hide();
```

tried

```
var v= $('div[id^="readOnly"]').find("img");
$(v).hide();
```

It's not working on form load; but this script works in "Firebug 'console' Run

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run this after document is ready:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

            $('div[id^="readOnly"]').find("img").hide(); 

            //or just:
             $("img","#readOnly").hide();

});
```

The `ready` function makes sure the script runs after the DOM is ready and loaded

Comment: it didn't work am looking someother alternative to remove these images

Comment: it does work, http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/xskoD  make sure you dont forget to load Jquery into the page

Comment: I have multiple divs with readonly_1 readOnly_2 etc., so am using id=^readOnly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#readOnly' ).find('img').each(function(){    
       $(this).css('display','none'); 
    });
});
```

Here is a working JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QR2wE/5/

Comment: PS - I would use the document ready event vs the onLoad event. Why wait for the images to load to hide them (as would be the case with onLoad)?

Answer (score 0):

Should be all you need:

```
$("#readOnly img").hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnyWL/)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this question 
[Call function after document and image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381603/how-to-call-function-after-document-ready-and-image-load)

Using the document ready function for jQuery doesn't guarantee that the image is rendered in the page.

```
$('div[id^="readOnly"]').find("img").load(function(){
   //hide your image
})
```