# Creating Class on Image with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I am trying to add a class to images when they are landscape using the following code:

```
  $('.gallery img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()) {
      $(this).addClass('landscape');        
    }
  });
```

The code is working some times, but sometimes the class is not added, thus the styles I have are not applied. I have tried with and without the $(document).ready function, along with putting it next to the images rather than at the end of the code, but nothing is consistently adding the class to the landscape images. I'm not sure what else to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's only going to work on images that are wider than they are tall.

Comment: Are the images already in the DOM when you run this?

Comment: @Dan, I'm pretty sure that's what's meant by "when they are landscape"

Comment: It seems you should listen to the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) event before checking the dimensions.

Comment: It sounds like the height and width are not what you think they are.

Comment: @PaulRoub maybe...but maybe not

Comment: @Dan it's the generally accepted meaning of "landscape", and it's *literally*, *explicitly* the *only* condition used to decide on adding a class named "landscape". I feel confident in taking the leap.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(this.src, $(this).width(), $(this).height())`, so you can see what values are being used for each image.

Comment: Note that `document.ready()` doesn't imply that any given image has loaded. An unloaded image definitely won't give meaningful dimensions. Unfortunately, detecting when a group of images *is* loaded can be tricky. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381603/how-to-call-function-after-document-ready-and-image-load

Comment: it's probably what @undefined said.

Comment: I am working with images that are wider than they are tall, which is landscape. Thank you Paul. That link was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Also listen to a load event, since some images might not be loaded (and therefore have unknown width/height):

```
// Put this in your $(document).ready
function handleImage($image) {
  if ($image.width() > $image.height()) {
    $image.addClass('landscape');        
  }
}
$('.gallery img').each(function() {
  handleImage($(this));
}).load(function() {
  handleImage($(this));
});
```

Note that having `width` and `height` attributes on image tags is recommended if you know the dimensions beforehand. Adding those attributes would void the need to have an `onload` handler.